# Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a cloud VM that runs my Hyperledger Fabric network (i.e., inside the VM are docker containers that run the peers, orderer, CAs, couchdbs). I also have a node.js application on Kubernetes (in the same VPC) that connects to the VM. However, whenever the application tries to connect to the blockchain via org1's connection profile, I get this error:

```
2021-03-16T02:28:46.320Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-03-16T02:28:46.320Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer.example.com:7050 url:grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050 timeout:3000
2021-03-16T02:28:46.320Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer.example.com:7050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
```

###### More details:

In the application, I use this to connect:
`await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false}});`

Before I changed `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP` and `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` from `peer.org.example.com` to the VM's internal IP address, it also produced the same errors for all discovered peers in the network *(please see `docker-compose-test-net.yaml` below)*.

When I changed `ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS` from `0.0.0.0` to the VM's IP address, I couldn't build the network successfully.

`docker-compose-test-net.yaml`:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  test:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - test

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      # - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=<VM's IP Address>:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=<VM's IP Address>:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=<VM's IP Address>:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    networks:
      - test

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      # - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7055
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=<VM's IP Address>:7055
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7055
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7056
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7056
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7055
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=<VM's IP Address>:7055
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7055
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=<VM's IP Address>:7055
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7055:7055
    networks:
      - test

  ... same goes for peer0.org2.example.com and peer1.org2.example.com ...
```

What should my configuration be so that the discovery service can successfully locate the orderer in my VM?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the `asLocalhost: false` to `asLocalhost: true` ? If your network and application are running on the same VPS you have to set asLocalhost var to true

Comment: I have and it couldn't find both the orderer and the peers. Aside from `Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer.example.com:7050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer.example.com:7050, url:grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true`, it also says `Unable to connect to the discovered peer 10.138.0.226:9051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: <VM IP>:9051, url:grpcs://localhost:9051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true`

Comment: if possible, can you share your connection profile?